# Export/Extract External Blender Addons

Tags: add-on

I've been using the new **Blender Cloud Sync Addon** to Install my Blender Build on multiple computers but i've run into an issue.

So it transfers all blender preferences and some Addons. But it doesn't transfer External 3rd party addons ***(Ie: Renderman, Retopoflow, Hardops)***.

Since i use loads of them it'd take me a while to download them back and keep a backup, It's possible but i hope there's a way to get them straight from my Blender install and manually install them elsewhere.

Hope you can help me on this:

**I think it's on:** *blender / 2.79 / scripts / addons.*

**But for some reason i can't find any external addon there**

Comment: Thee are two default locations addons will be in. All the ones shipped with blender are in `blender/2.79/scripts/addons`, but any installed from the user preferences will be in the [user path](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/getting_started/installing/configuration/directories.html).

Comment: Riiiight of course, i totally forgot about the user path folder, thank you!
I'll do my backups now!!

Comment: You should suggest to them that they add an option to sync user installed addons.